# Mystical 'The type is defined in an assembly that is not referenced' error when using extension methods

Tags: c#, .net, compilation, dependencies, extension-methods

After implementing few new, quite standard classes I bumped into error

`"The type 'SomeNamespace.ModelBase' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'AAA.UI'"`

Error is quite standard and I have resolved it many times previously. But this time I spent 2 hours and still have no idea what's wrong with my code.

After some commenting/uncommenting code I discovered that error is caused by 3 extension methods, defined in commonly-used assembly "CCC", and used in assembly "BBB", which contains some business logic. Obviously I don't want to add reference from "BBB" to "AAA.UI" due to architectural considerations. But as I discovered, **there is a reference BBB > CCC > DDD > AAA.UI** (due to old classes I haven't touched and not referenced by extensions causing my problem). I know it's very bad already, but I'm not willing to make it even worse.

What's interesting is that **CCC doesn't reference AAA.UI directly and compiles well**.  **So how can usage of extension from CCC in BBB require reference to AAA.UI for BBB?**

**Additional investigation details:**

Class, containing extension methods is NOT partial, is NOT derived from anything (well, from `System.Object` to be correct), does NOT have equally-named classes or extensions in other namespaces, and any types it uses as well as their property types are not defined in AAA.UI assembly.
I have also tried few similarly-named threads on SO, but nothing helped.

To ensure my extensions does not reference anything from AAA.UI, I recreated the same behavior with the following extension (which I put into CCC project):

```
public static class TestExtensions
{
    public static string SomeExtension(this int x)
    {
        return "";
    }
}
```

Again, when it is not used in BBB, then BBB does NOT require reference to AAA.UI. But once I call SomeExtension() in BBB, it now requires a reference to AAA.UI. How is that possible???

Going further, when I change my extension to become regular static method, dependency requirement is removed again. Looks like C# compiler does some crazy magic with extension methods.

Comment: That's because your extension methods are exposing some classes from AAA.UI, just hide them or encapsulate them, it should work,

Comment: @Gusman, I double-checked that 3 times already and that's not true. Extensions expose types which are not located in AAA.UI, and neither of their internal properties and fields reference AAA.UI as well. That would be too easy =)

Comment: Problem can be that CCC I has some public interface that is used in another public interface inside BBB that is then used In some public interface of AAA.UI

Comment: @m.rogalski Do you mean interface as my extensions, or some unrelated interface could cause that?

Comment: Something like CCC.class1 will be referenced in BBB.class2 which then will be referenced in AAA.UI.class3

Comment: @m.rogalski I think it is not the case since AAA.UI doesn't have reference to BBB. So it's classes couldn't reference classes from BBB.

Comment: AAA.UI maybe not but then it have this DDD which then exposes though public interface some type from CCC which then can expose types from BBB

Comment: And then in the compile time your main assembly cannot reference the assembly that is publicly exposed through some other assemblies

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134517/discussion-between-oleksandr-pshenychnyy-and-m-rogalski).